# Linq retrieve non repeated values

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Event_Day and Event_Session which is like this

Event_Day

```
 Event_Day_Id(PK)    Event_Id     DayNo    Day_Date
    420               120           1      20/6/2013
    421               120           2      21/6/2013
    422               120           3      22/6/2013
```

Event_Session

```
 Event_Session_Id(PK) Event_Id     Event_Day_Id  
    170               120           420         
    171               120           420         
    172               120           420
    173               120           421
    174               120           421
    175               120           421
```

I Want to retrieve by comparing data from these two table using Linq

```
Event_Day_Id    DayNo        DayDate
   420            1         21/6/2013
   421            2         22/6/2013
```

Pls help me to retrieve data using Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `Enumerable.Distinct` LINQ method.  Read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx).  You first want to do a join on the two tables (suppose your data sets are `eventSessions` and `eventDays`):

```
var dayInfo = from sess in eventSessions
join day in eventDays
on sess.Event_Day_Id equals day.Event_Day_Id
select new { Event_Day_Id = sess.Event_Day_Id, DayNo = day.DayNo, DayDate = sess.Day_Date };
```

If you are unfamiliar with LINQ equijoins, read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx).

After that, you want to use the `Distinct` method:

```
var uniqueDayInfo = dayInfo.Distinct();
```

Note that `Distinct` also has an overload that takes in an `IEqualityComparer`, in cases where you do not want to use default equality comparison.  The initial LINQ query (the one that initializes the `dayInfo` variable) ends with a projection to an anonymous type.  The default equality comparison for anonymous types runs default equality comparison on all the properties.  Read more about anonymous types and the overridden `Equals` method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

If all the selected properties are simple (`ints`, `DateTimes`, etc.), this should be sufficient for the `Distinct` to work as desired without providing the optional `IEqualityComparer` argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! and prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a helper class to create a comparer (shown below) you can do it like this:

```
var unique_session = Sessions.Distinct(
   new GenComp<Event_Session>((a,b) => 
       (a.Event_Id == b.Event_Id) && (a.Event_Day_Id == b.Event_Day_Id),
       (a) => a.Event_Id.GetHashCode()+a.Event_Day_Id.GetHashCode()));

var result = unique_session.Join(Days,
       s =>  new { Event_Id = s.Event_Id, Event_Day_Id = s.Event_Day_Id },
       d =>  new { Event_Id = d.Event_Id, Event_Day_Id = d.Event_Day_Id },
       (s, d) => new { Event_Day_Id = d.Event_Day_Id, 
                       DayNo = d.DayNo,
                       DayDate = d.Day_Date });
```

Here is the helper class

```
public class GenComp<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> 
{
    public Func<T, T, bool> comp { get; private set; }
    public Func<T, int> hash { get; private set; }

    public GenComp(Func<T, T, bool> inComp, Func<T,int> inHash)
    {
        comp = inComp;
        hash = inHash;
    }

    public GenComp(Func<T, T, bool> inComp)
    {
        comp = inComp;
        hash = null;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return comp(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)  
    {  
        return hash == null ? obj.GetHashCode() : hash(obj);  
    }  
}
```

Full source code test which runs under LinqPad is here: https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/5820080

Which returns the following:

[image: result]

Note: I suggest LinqPad at LinqPad.com for solving these types of problems - it rocks.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer! it works but i cannot create a list to add data

Comment: @Mazher - Did you follow the link to the source?